# Color fade a line in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, gradient

I had already a similar question. I know now how to color fade rectangles. But I was trying now for almost an hour and I couldn't figure out how to do a fading for a line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\draw[line width=4pt,orange] 
  ([yshift=-62pt]current page.north west) -- +(14cm,0pt);
\draw[orange,line width=1pt] 
  ([yshift=-175pt,xshift=+14cm]current page.north west) -- +(5.1cm,0pt);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want the lines to fade from left orange to right white.

Comment: A line can be be considered as a very thin rectangle...

Comment: @PaulGaborit of course I tried that, but it seems there is a minimum width for a rectangle. At least I couldn't get it as thin as I wanted

Comment: I meant miminum height

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A line can be be considered as a very thin rectangle...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
([yshift=-62pt]current page.north west)
+(0,-2pt) rectangle +(14cm,2pt); 

\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
([yshift=-175pt,xshift=+14cm]current page.north west)
+(0,-.5pt) rectangle +(5.1cm,0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: my apologies, I did it with a `\node` don't know if that was the reason why it wasn't working

Comment: @AdrianPfeifle A node uses implicitly `inner sep` distance (initially `.3333em`). If you want to use a node, try it with `inner sep=0`.

Comment: thanks for the hint, now what I tried before is also working

Comment: Hey Paul, any ideas how to integrate your MWE with the one here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376873/trouble-merging-two-mwes-tikz-mdframed ?