# Trouble merging two MWE's (tikz, mdframed) // inserting a fading line

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

How to integrate [**MWE 1**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216067/color-fade-a-line-in-tikzpicture)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
([yshift=-62pt]current page.north west)
+(0,-2pt) rectangle +(14cm,2pt); 

\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
([yshift=-175pt,xshift=+14cm]current page.north west)
+(0,-.5pt) rectangle +(5.1cm,0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

into **MWE 2**

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{anyfontsize,multirow,mwe}

\newenvironment{infobox}[2][green]{%
  \begin{mdframed}[%
    skipabove=4ex plus .5ex minus .5ex,%
    skipbelow=4ex plus .5ex minus .5ex,%
    frametitle={\sffamily #2},%
    innertopmargin=2ex,%
    innerbottommargin=2ex,%
    frametitleaboveskip=1.618ex,%
    frametitlebelowskip=1.618ex,%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=#1,%
    linecolor=#1]%
}{%
  \end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont
  \sffamily
  \scshape
  \color{green!50!black}
Hello World!
\end{center}
\begin{infobox}[green!80!black]{\textcolor{white}{Some Random Title}}
  \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1cm}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \multirow{7}{*}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}} & Date & 22 February 2002 \\
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
    &   &   \\
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{infobox}

\begin{infobox}[green!80!black]{Another Title}
  \begin{list}{...}{...}
    \item[...] ...
  \end{list}
\end{infobox}
\end{document}
```

?

---

Ultimately, I would like to draw a faded line (as in MWE 1) somewhere in MWE 2. MWE 1 is just an example.

So desired output should look sth like this:

[image]

and here's an attempt at "merging" the codes:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{anyfontsize,multirow,mwe}

\newenvironment{infobox}[2][green]{%
  \begin{mdframed}[%
    skipabove=4ex plus .5ex minus .5ex,%
    skipbelow=4ex plus .5ex minus .5ex,%
    frametitle={\sffamily #2},%
    innertopmargin=2ex,%
    innerbottommargin=2ex,%
    frametitleaboveskip=1.618ex,%
    frametitlebelowskip=1.618ex,%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=#1,%
    linecolor=#1]%
}{%
  \end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont
  \sffamily
  \scshape
  \color{green!50!black}
  Hello World!
\end{center}
\begin{infobox}[green!80!black]{\textcolor{white}{Some Random Title}}
  \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1cm}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \multirow{7}{*}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}} & Date & 22 February 2002 \\
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
    &   &   \\
    %%%%%%%%%% (unsuccessful attempt to incorporate "MWE 1" %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
([yshift=-62pt]current page.north west)
+(0,-2pt) rectangle +(14cm,2pt); 

\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
([yshift=-175pt,xshift=+14cm]current page.north west)
+(0,-.5pt) rectangle +(5.1cm,0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{infobox}

\begin{infobox}[green!80!black]{Another Title}
  \begin{list}{...}{...}
    \item[...] ...
  \end{list}
%%%%%%%%%% (unsuccessful attempt to incorporate "MWE 1" %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
([yshift=-62pt]current page.north west)
+(0,-2pt) rectangle +(14cm,2pt); 

\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
([yshift=-175pt,xshift=+14cm]current page.north west)
+(0,-.5pt) rectangle +(5.1cm,0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{infobox}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Untested: Try to use some overlay and `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed`

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you want.  Should the line be a fixed position relative to the frame, or do you just want a line inside the box "at the current position"

Comment: @AndrewSwann the latter. will post an image of the desired look in a bit.

Comment: @AndrewSwann done.

Comment: Don't use the minimal class, it is too minimal.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `tcolorbox` does look like an interesting alternative to `mdframed`. thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm using the article class. This MWE was quickly copy-pasted from another question.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you do not want a page overlay and can just draw the rectangle directly

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{anyfontsize,multirow,mwe}

\newenvironment{infobox}[2][green]{%
  \begin{mdframed}[%
    skipabove=4ex plus .5ex minus .5ex,%
    skipbelow=4ex plus .5ex minus .5ex,%
    frametitle={\sffamily #2},%
    innertopmargin=2ex,%
    innerbottommargin=2ex,%
    frametitleaboveskip=1.618ex,%
    frametitlebelowskip=1.618ex,%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=#1,%
    linecolor=#1]%
}{%
  \end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont
  \sffamily
  \scshape
  \color{green!50!black}
  Hello World!
\end{center}
\begin{infobox}[green!80!black]{\textcolor{white}{Some Random Title}}
  \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1cm}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \multirow{7}{*}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}} & Date & 22 February 2002 \\
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
    &   &   \\
    %%%%%%%%%% (unsuccessful attempt to incorporate "MWE 1" %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
([yshift=-62pt]current page.north west)
+(0,-2pt) rectangle +(14cm,2pt); 

\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
([yshift=-175pt,xshift=+14cm]current page.north west)
+(0,-.5pt) rectangle +(5.1cm,0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{infobox}

\begin{infobox}[green!80!black]{Another Title}
  \begin{list}{...}{...}
    \item[...] ...
  \end{list}
%%%%%%%%%% (unsuccessful attempt to incorporate "MWE 1" %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[left color=orange,right color=white]
rectangle +(14cm,2pt); 
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{infobox}


\end{document}
```

Comment: what's a "page overlay"? like a "layer" in photoshop/gimp?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty see your mwe1 `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]` that is specifying a picture at absolute page coordinates overprinting any normal content, it's not part of the normal text flow. That failed mostly as you were using minimal class (unrelated to mdframed) but since the mdframe _is_ part of the text content and moves with the text I don't think you want an overlay here at all.

Comment: true. that happens when quickly grabbing code without rtfm etc first ;) http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/remember-picture/